# mb_YTPlayer - Can't insert YouTube video inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I'm trying to embed an Youtube video inside a Div, but the video appears outside the Div.

I'm using a library called mb YTPlayer to do that.

My website [demo](http://geocities.ws/nbridge/):

I would like to put the video inside the div with red background.

My code:

CSS:

```
.screen{
   background-image: url('img/window.png');
   width: 950px;
   height:390px;
   margin:auto;
}

.videoprom{
   padding-top:91px;
   padding-left:5px;
}

.videoprom span{
    display:block;
    width:940px;
    height:390px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="screen">
<div class="videoprom">
<span class="test">
<a id="video" class="player" data-property=
  "{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLUNWYt3q1w',containment:'.test',autoplay:true, mute:true, startAt:015, stopAt:110, opacity:5}"></a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a relative positioning to the div to fit into the container and then adjust the padding or margin.

```
.screen {
    background-image: url("img/window.png");
    height: 390px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 950px;
}

#wrapper_mbYTP_video {
   margin-top: 90px;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Video fit inside background]

Comment: I tried in that way but it didn't work how I expected, but I turned the video prom span relative, and It worked, thanks a lot.